# is there a function to link php pages on local?

Tags: php, redirect

I'm testing a website right now on a localhost, I want to redirect from one php page to another php page on the same localhost, I wanna test if it's working, when the page redirects to the other page it gives me [the error in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7gig.png), Edit: this is my code:

```
        if($pass==$passwords){
            switch ($position){
                case "Admin":
                    header("Location:https://www.google.com/");
                    break;
                case "emp":
                    header("Location:https://www.facebook.com/");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This should help: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: how we can help you without see your code ?

Comment: You just need to check that you set the correct URL in your redirect

Answer (score 1):

You can use **header** in php:

For example:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

Check detail documentation about [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)